# Denial of Service against an asynchronous Web service

Tags: denial-of-service, web-service

Is it possible to perform a denial of service attack on an asynchronous web service?  Isn't the operating system supposed to release the thread? It shouldn't matter if someone attacking a system would be  throwing thousands/millions of requests per second at that server.

Does anyone have an opinion on this?

Comment: what kind of DoS are you talking about?

Comment: Application layer

Comment: [This post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29749/denial-of-service-attack-in-asynchronous-communication) describes a related, though opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

If, by asynchronous, you mean a web server like vertx/undertow that puts requests onto an event bus an handles them from a thread pool, then DoS should still be possible, though you **may** require a higher load if you do an L7 flooding attack than when DoS-ing a threaded server like Apache.

The OS is indeed not creating and blocking a single thread per request, and instead serving from a pool of event-driven workers, which means that CPU exhaustion is harder to achieve. However, at the network level, there are still a large number of open connections, and the system may still run out of file descriptors and be unable to handle new connections.

Indeed, I did some simple testing to benchmark Apache Tomcat v/s vertx and found that on identically configured AWS EC2 instances, vertx has a capacity that is four times higher than Apache, but still crashes even from a single L7 flood generator.